# Reshaping a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like this, where the columns are as follows:

1. `userid` is as the name suggests
2. `name` is each api event
3. `count`is the frequency of the event

> [image]

So, I want a dataframe which looks like this:

```
userid    api_event_1          api_event_2          ....   api_event_n
17        count_of_apievent1   count_of_apievent2   ....   count_of_apieventn
2345      count_of_apievent1   count_of_apievent2   ....   count_of_apieventn
 .              .                   .                  .        .
 .              .                   .                  .        .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
df.pivot(index='userid', columns='name', values='count_of_name')
```

Where df is your pandas dataframe
(will insert Nan if some values do not exist. For example if there is no count for event A for user X)

For filling in `0`instead of a `NaN` where the user do not have the api event, you can do this:

```
df.pivot(index='userid', columns='name', values='count_of_name').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Perfect :)  Is there any way I can convert the `NaN`s to `0`s where the user don't have that particular api event?

Comment: Just use df.pivot( ... ).fillna(0) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DataFrame's [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) method:

```
print(df.transpose())
```

Or just:

```
print(df.T)
```

Comment: This does not give me the `userid`'s as rows :)